# CSS 2 column page with float not working

Tags: html, css

I've read through the many articles here on CSS Float but still can't get my simple example to work.  I'm trying to get 2 columns on my page using this html:

```
<div id="mainContent" style="clear: both;">
  <div id="categoryColumn" >
    <h1 >
      Recipe Categories
      </h1>
      <ul>
        <li>cat1</li>
        <li>cat2</li>
        <li>cat3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="menuColumn">
    <h1>
      Weekly Menus
    </h1>
      <ul>
        <li>menu1</li>
        <li>menu2</li>
        <li>menu3</li>
        <li>menu4</li>
        <li>menu5</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
#categoryColumn
{
    background-color: yellow;
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
}

#menuColumn
{
    background-color: red;
  width: 500px;

}
```

I know the divs are being recognized because the colors are correct, but the two lists are appearing on top of each other, not side by side. I want to top column (categoryColumn) on the left, and the bottom one on the right. Am I using the float wrong?

Comment: have you tried using % instead of fixed width? like width: 50%

Comment: Do you have a fixed page width or is the width of mainContent less than 1000px to accommodate both categoryColumn and menuColumn side-by-side?

Comment: which type u want this alignment any example ? giv me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

float needs to put on menuColumn as well.

Comment: That was it!  I was floating the category column left (which was already left), and not floating the menu col at all.  I floated the menu col right and that fixed it.  thx.

Answer (score 1):

add float:left to #menuColumn - see http://jsfiddle.net/UjLeK/

Answer (score 1):

Hey Brad Irby need to float both div each other, Just check it... http://jsfiddle.net/mnuVB/